# Edit ... parameter in R

Tags: r

I'm having troubles understanding how the `...`parameter works in R, I can't find a complete documentation, is it some kind of editable object?

I'm writing an R package and I would like to write a function that uses the dots, to pass them to another function (`plot`), but I want to pass some parameters to the inner function only if they are not in `...`. I know that using `list(...)` I can check if they have been specified, but I don't know if I can add them to `...` otherwise. What's the best way to make this work?

I tried to pass an edited `pars= list(...)` to the inner function `plot(...= pars)`, but it didn't work. Actually in the end I found a solution, which is updating the list `pars` trough `modifyList` and then using `do.call` to pass them to the inner function, but this feels a bit intricate to me, there is any simpler solution?

Comment: Some doc in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) at the Functions / **...** section.

Comment: Since you know the arguments you only want to pass if not included in the parent function, why not create defaults in the child function. Then manipulate theese values in the parent function if needed.

Comment: Janhoo is right, the simple and idiomatic way to do this is to use argument defaults. eg: `foo <- function(x, ...) bar(x, ...); bar <- function(x, log = FALSE) if (log) log(x) else x; foo(10); foo(10, log=TRUE)`

Comment: Maybe he's using someone else's functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur and Janhoo made some good suggestions, but in the end I see that the straightforward way I hoped to find doesn't exist. So in the end the best solution to me is the one I sketched in the question:

```
pars_user= list(...)
pars_default= list(a= 1, b= 2)
pars_fixed= list(c= 3, d= 4)

pars= modifyList(pars_default, pars_user)
pars= modifyList(pars, pars_fixed)
do.call(function, pars)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass `...` along as so:

```
# weird way to construct a linear function
f0 <- function (x, b=1) x+b
f1 <- function (x, a=2, ...){

   # INITIAL WRONG ANSWER  stopifnot(exists("b")) # see comments

   if("b" %in% names(list(...))){
     f0(a*x, ...)
   }else{
     f0(a*x, b=4, ...) # Only makes sense if b=4 is a default that has meaning
                       # in f1 but not outside of f1 ; or if you cannot change
                       # the definition of f0 (imported functions). Otherwise,
                       # you'd better change the default in f0.
   }
}
f1(10)
f1(10, b=3)
```

Comment: That's not how you check that `b` is provided in `...`. Consider the case where `b` is defined in the global environment. The correct way is to catch `...` in a list.

Comment: With `"b" %in% eval(substitute(alist(...)))` then?

Comment: I often see `dots <- list(...)` than you can check if `"b" %in% names(dots)`. Doesn't work with positional arguments.

Comment: Corrected. `eval(substitute(alist(...)))` and `list(...)` give the same result as far as I have tested.

Comment: Not sure if I answer the "I want to pass some parameters to the inner function only if they are not in .... " part though.

Comment: no in fact I know that it is possible to pass the dots to inner function, that's not the question

Comment: What about now?

Comment: But you're right, if I were to change several arguments, I would have to build a function call.